# Is it possible to designate the selection of the row representing a group in the results of a query with a group by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The following query,

```
select shelf_id, issue_date, current_qty
from Stock
where barcode = '555' and issue_date <= '2018-05-30 14:28:32'
```

will give the following results,

```
10  2018-05-25 00:00:00 5
10  2018-05-28 00:00:00 55
5   2018-05-29 00:00:00 100
```

Adding `group by shelf_id` will lead to that result,

```
10  2018-05-25 00:00:00 5
5   2018-05-29 00:00:00 100
```

The desired result is the following.

```
10  2018-05-28 00:00:00 55
5   2018-05-29 00:00:00 100
```

The reasoning behind this, is that for each group I would like to return the row of the group with the latest `issue_date`.

`limit 1` limits the total groups returned to just one,
`having issue_date...` would be a possible solution but I do not know how to get the closest date to Max(issue_date)

Is it possible at all to accomplish this without using a subquery?

**Edit:**
The second condition in the where clause `issue_date <= '2018-05-30 14:28:32'` is a user input `issue_date <= ?2` ment to initially filter the table, the query then should group by the results per shelf_if, but return the row with the closest day to the max(issue_date). So I don't see how I could just replace this condition with a subquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `group by`!  You are trying to filter the rows.  Here is one method:

```
select s.*
from stock s
where s.issue_date = (select max(s2.issue_date) from stock s2 where s2.shelf_id = s.shelf_id);
```

As a bonus, with an index on `stock(shelf_id, issue_date)`, the performance should be better than the `group by`.

Comment: Table aliases are really giving me a hard time in MySQL due to multiple joins, the query in my question is a simpler version of the real one. I am trying to implement your answer but so far I am only getting results consisting of one row.

Comment: @Karapapas . . . You need the correlation clause to get more than one result.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *identify* column then you can use `LIMIT` clause:

```
select s.*
from Stock s
where barcode = '555' and issue_date <= '2018-05-30 14:28:32' and 
      identity_col = (select identity_col
                      from Stock s1
                      where s1.shelf_id = s.shelf_id
                      order by s1.issue_date desc
                      limit 1
                     );
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying `If I have identify column`. Is it a way to join you subquery?

Comment: @Karapapas. . . `identify` which is represent your table data ordering was inserted.

Answer (score 0):

you may try it this way

```
select ST.shelf_id, ST.issue_date, ST.current_qty
from Stock as ST INNER JOIN (select shelf_id, MAX(issue_date) AS issue_date
from Stock
where barcode = '555' and issue_date <= '2018-05-30 14:28:32'
GROUP BY shelf_id) AS A ON ST.shelf_id = A.shelf_id and ST.issue_date = A.issue_date
```

as long as (shelf_id,issue_date) are unique, this should work, please let me know if im wrong